# Futures, TimeoutException, and Callables with finally blocks

Tags: java, concurrency, future, callable, timeoutexception

Will a finally block withing a thread be called if the Callable is canceled via future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)?

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<Future<?>>{
    public Future<?> call(){
        Connection conn = pool.getConnection();
        try {
            ... 
        } catch(CatchExceptions ce){
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    } 
}

... 

future.get(executionTimeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I am aware that finally will always be called, but i'm guessing i'm missing something regarding how threads are interrupted. Here is a test i ran that did not show my finally block being fired.

```
@Test
public void testFuture(){
    ExecutorService pool =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    try {
        pool.submit(new TestCallable()).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class TestCallable implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        try{
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            break;
        }
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT!");
            throw e;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("FINALLY BLOCK RAN!");
        }
    }

}
```

Looks like if i add awaitTermination it runs.
This test passes...

```
public void testFuture(){
    ExecutorService pool =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    try {
        pool.submit(new TestCallable()).get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`future.get(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) does not cancel a thread.  It only waits for the thread to finish, throwing `TimeoutException` if the wait timed out.

[`future.cancel(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) *will* cause the thread to be *interrupted*.  This may or may not stop your thread from processing.  It depends on what is happening inside of your `try ...` section.  For example, `Thread.sleep(...)`, `Object.wait(...)`, and other methods throw `InterruptedException` when a thread is interrupted.  Otherwise you need to check for the thread interrupt flag with

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // maybe stop the thread or whatever you want
    return;
}
```

If the `try` block is entered, the `finally` block is *always* called (interrupt or not) unless there is some sort of JVM fault and crash.  I suspect that your thread is not being interrupted at all so just keeps running.

Comment: just a little comment: finally block is always called, if try block begin its execution. If thread didn't enter try block and was terminated before, then finally of course will not be called.